# Return generic type from Spring JdbcTemplate's queryForObject method

Tags: java, spring, generics, jdbc

I want to create a generic method which should look like that:

```
public<T,S,R> getCell(S column,R arg){
 return jdbcTemplate.queryForObject("select ? from PASS_IND_SP_LINK where PASS_IND_LINK_ID=?", new Object[]{column,arg}, T.class); 
}
```

But `T.class` not compiles. What can i do to make this method return `T` type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all you need a return type of your method. But if you want to return T you can do it like that:

```
 public<T,S,R> T getCell(S val1, R val2, Class<T> theClass){

    return jdbcTemplate.queryForObject("select ? from PASS_IND_SP_LINK where PASS_IND_LINK_ID=?", new Object[]{column,arg}, theClass);
}
```

You will have to pass the class too. T in the generics is just a meta data for a type. It is not an instance to call it's methods and get it's class. You need to pass it in the parameters. Something like:

```
myObject.getCell("val1" , "val2", String.class);
```

Comment: Ok. I understood. Thank you!